# Adding a second monitor via ethernet

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, ethernet

My DisplayPort connection is buggy and will only work when in a position that I can't ever seem to find. I've sent it off to repairs and the guy said that the board connecting to the socket is cracked and needs to be replaced, but he couldn't find a new board to replace it with.

Because of that, I'm wondering if I can connect my MBP to my TV monitor using the other outputs on my MBP instead of using the DisplayPort. This has led me to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMDGx.jpg) and has left me wondering, is it possible to just connect an ethernet cable from my mac into that and then my TV?

There is an option listed in the hardware settings of the Ethernet section in the network settings pane that mentions AVB/EAV Mode, which it apparently allows streaming audio / video over ethernet?

To me it sounds like it would work, but I want confirmation before I go out and buy these adapters.

Comment: The link to 'this' is to an image of a device, not a description of the device itself.

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking past the HDMI, Thunderbolt/mini-DisplayPort, and/or USB C ports?  (you don't specify what generation of MBP you have)  Any of those to DisplayPort cables are pretty common.

Comment: @ernie I'm using the 13" mid 2012 MBP. It has a firewire, ethernet, mini display port and two usb A ports. Currently the mini display port is not working properly and so it does not provide a reliable connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device you linked to is HDMI over CAT5/5e/6 cable, *not* Ethernet.  There's a major difference.  It's sending video signals over the 4 pairs of wire, not establishing a TCP link between the two devices.

[image]

> ...is it possible to just connect an ethernet cable from my mac into
>   that and then my TV?

Yes, but you need more than just a Mac that supports AVB.  You need a device that is an AVB audio device.  In other words, you can't just stream audio/video to any device with an Ethernet port.

IMO, AVB is a nice feature, but it won't have the reliability and quality of a proper DisplayPort connection.  Keep in mind that [DP v1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Specifications) has 32Gb/s bandwidth where as typical Ethernet is only 1Gb/s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if macOS supports video over AVB, I've only seen AVB audio products in use w/ macOS so far.

Probably a viable alternative would be to hook up an Apple TV to your TV and use it for display mirroring/extending via AirPlay.